# Can you provide information or links that discuss using resource state over session or DB state?

Tags: java, rest, resources, state

[There is a talk here by Stefan Tilkov](http://www.parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#slide=1;talk=31817742;title=RESTful%20Design%2C%20Patterns%20and%20Anti-Patterns), where he is describing REST architecture at its core. I haven't watched all of it, but in the portion where he talks about the 5 Principles of REST (slides 12-19) he mentions maintaining state through the resource (i.e. -- the URI). His example is a shopping cart. Usually the state of your shopping cart is maintained in the session, but he makes the comment (paraphrasing here) that this is an incorrect interface implementation, since you can't "send" your session to a colleague, but you could send the resource state, which would then have all of the items in your cart. I found the concept to be interesting, and I was wondering if anyone has any additional information, resources, links, videos, etc., that actually discuss architecture implementations for this sort of thing (preferably in Java). Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry, I'm going to make a brief edit here -- I'm not talking about wanting information on REST implementations per se, but wanting disadvantages/advantages of actually using resource state extensively over session/db state.

Comment: Poor analogy - why would I send someone my shopping cart when I could direct them to my wishlist/gift registry...

Comment: @OMGPonies - One possible case could be in an external approval or purchasing scenario. eg. Someone else has to approve my purchase, or actually make the purchase for me, so instead of sending them a list of individual items and associated quantities, I simply send them the entire cart that just awaits the payment and shipping details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the clearest explanations of the disadvantages of session state comes directly from Roy Fielding's [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) where he introduces REST.  (Emphasis is mine)

> We next add a constraint to the
> client-server interaction:
> communication must be stateless in
> nature, as in the
> client-stateless-server (CSS) style of
> Section 3.4.3 (Figure 5-3), such that
> **each request from client to server**
> **must contain all of the information**
> **necessary to understand the request**,
> **and cannot take advantage of any**
> **stored context on the server**.
>
> **Session
> state is therefore kept entirely on
> the client.**
>
> This constraint induces the properties of **visibility, reliability,
> and scalability.**
>
> **Visibility** is
> improved because a monitoring system
> does not have to look beyond a single
> request datum in order to determine
> the full nature of the request.
>
> **Reliability** is improved because it
> eases the task of recovering from
> partial failures [133].
>
> **Scalability** is
> improved because not having to store
> state between requests allows the
> server component to quickly free
> resources, and further simplifies
> implementation because the server
> doesn't have to manage resource usage
> across requests.

Roy does go on to say the application of this constraint is a design trade-off and there are negative impacts of this choice.

Once you choose not to use session state in your application architecture, then you are left with maintaining things like shopping carts in one of two ways.  Either the cart is maintained completely by the client application, or it is stored as Resource state.  What makes something a Resource is that it is identified by a URI and can be manipulated by the standard verbs of the interface.  If you do store the cart as a Resource, then as Stefan says you can send a link to the resource to a colleague. With this approach, the shopping cart can be implemented as you do any other resource.

Comment: Thankd Darrel -- and thanks for the link to the dissertation as I hadn't considered reading that would probably help with better understanding some of the underlying details.

Answer (score 1):

> and I was wondering if anyone has any additional information, resources, links, videos, etc., that actually discuss architecture implementations for this sort of thing (preferably in Java). Thanks!

To the point, a "friendly url controller" would suffice. Create a Filter and/or Servlet which extracts the [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) or [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29), creates some javabean with the REST data, takes action accordingly using the command pattern and finally forwards to the JSP page in question to present the data.

Keep in mind that URL's are restricted in length to certain borders which depends on the webbrowser and webserver used. I'd recommend to not make it any longer than 255 characters. If you really need to store more information in the URL, consider GZipping and Base64encoding it and append it to the end of the URL, something like `http://example.com/cart/2j34hfg5jh2g5bnvcnb2vc452`. It doesn't make the URL more readable, no, but it works and can you can pass lot of information in.

Comment: Good info... especially the encoding portion as a way to get past the restriction on character lengths in the URL.